Delete matched rows and then insert all rows (Cancel & Replace technique)
For technical & functional reasons I would like to apply a Cancel & Replace method for all rows of my dataframe. The goal is to delete all matched rows of my dataframe (with the target table) and then insert all rows (without any filter).
Is this code correct?
deltaTableDf
    .alias("df_delta")
    .merge(dfToMerge.alias("my_df"), condition)
    .whenMatched
    .delete()
    .whenNotMatched
    .insertAll()
    .execute()

Or I have to separate the deleting process from the inserting one like this?
deltaTableDf
    .alias("df_delta")
    .merge(dfToMerge.alias("my_df"), condition)
    .whenMatched
    .delete()
    .execute()

  dfToMerge.write
    .option("overwriteSchema", "true")
    .format("delta")
    .mode(SaveMode.Append)
    .saveAsTable(my_delta_table)

